# Basic question about OOP Class Structure with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, oop, .net-3.5

I have this situation:

```
public class busOrder: IbusOrder
{
    public Order vOrder { get; set; }

    MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext();

    public busOrder(int pOrderId)
    {
         vOrder = db.Orders.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == pOrderId);
    }

    public int SaveNew()
    {
        ...
    }
    public int GetStatus()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

As you may have noticed, `Order` is a table in my **datacontext** and the constructor "fills" `vOrder` and I can do that very easily with link (one line).

But when I'm making calls to use the objects atributes I have to do it like this:

```
busOrder openOrder = new busOrder(someId);
```

then I have to do this to get the columns:

```
openOrder.vOrder.Date;
openOrder.vOrder.Status;
```

Is there any way for me to make this values more easily accessible (like `openOrder.Date`, without having to manually create and set them one by one in the class?

Comment: Not to nitpick but just as an FYI, typically class names and properties are Pascal cased in C#.

Comment: Object model problem?  Are you sure `Order` shouldn't be an abstract class that `busOrder` extends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use Dynamic Language Runtime.

EDIT: Well if you're using .NET 4.0 you could implement something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dynamic order = new BusOrder();
        Console.WriteLine(order.Test);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class BusOrder : DynamicObject
{
    private Order _order = new Order();

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        result = _order.GetType().GetProperty(binder.Name).GetValue(_order, null);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**AutoMapper**](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to copy values of properties between objects.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way that I know of.  When I've had to do this, I usually just write out the first property by hand and then copy and paste up a storm.

```
public int Status
{
   get { return this.vOrders.Status; }
   set { this.vOrders.Status = value; }
}
```